# Using a Volt::Model as a dictionary of Key/Value pairs

Tags: ruby, voltrb

I would like to use a Volt::Model as a reactive dictionary in a view.

Ideally, I would like something like this:

```
<dl>
  {{ dictionary.each do |key, val| }}
  <dt>Term: {{ key }}</dt>
  <dd>Definition: {{ val }}</dd>
  {{ end }}
</dl>
```

Is this possible in Volt without using an ArrayModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I don't have .each_pair working in bindings in Volt yet, its on the todo list.  Yea, you can use .keys.each do |key| in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. This works:

```
<dl>
  {{ dictionary.keys.each do |key| }}
  <dt>Term: {{ key }}</dt>
  <dd>Definition: {{ dictionary.get(key) }}</dd>
  {{ end }}
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

The version in the question should almost work. You just have to use each_pair instead of each.